# ORMLite - persisting LocalDateTiime - Unparseable date

Tags: java, ormlite, date-parsing

I'm using ORMLite to persist objects in an SQLite Database, but persisting LocalDateTime values does't work. I already configured a custom persister class like this:

```
public class LocalDateTimePersister extends TimeStampType {

private static final LocalDateTimePersister singleTon = new LocalDateTimePersister();

String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss";
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat);
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);

private LocalDateTimePersister() {
    super(SqlType.STRING, new Class<?>[] { LocalDateTime.class });
}

public static LocalDateTimePersister getSingleton() {
    return singleTon;
}

@Override
public Object javaToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, Object javaObject) {
    LocalDateTime dateTime = (LocalDateTime) javaObject;
    if (dateTime == null) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return dateTime.format(dtf);
    }
}

@Override
public Object sqlArgToJava(FieldType fieldType, Object sqlArg, int columnPos) {
    return LocalDateTime.parse((String) sqlArg, dtf);
}
```

}

It saves the value correctly, but loading the object causes this exception:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2023-10-15T12:57:46.000" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
```

The time value that was saved in the database is "2023-10-15T12:57:46", so I don't know where that string with the milliseconds value comes from. The breakpoint inside my javaToSqlArg method isn't hit and I can't see what's causing this error exactly.

Also, I noticed that there's no foreign key constraint being applied when creating the table, although the attributes are annotated appropriately. So child objects just stay in the database when I delete the parent object. Is there a way to change that without using a text query to create the table?

Comment: You should probably paste the full stack trace into your question (nicely formatted as code).

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2023-10-15T12:57:46.000" does not match (\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
> ```

If you look closely at the generated pattern error message, I see `\Q \E` in the middle when I would have expected `\QT\E`.  Are you sure that the pattern that generated the error was as you describe in the post?

```
(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q-\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q \E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q:\E(\p{Nd}++)\Q.\E(\p{Nd}++)
                                        ^^^^^
```

Any chance that your code really has:

```
String dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss";
```

If it does have the `T` then I'm not sure what's going on.
gray